# How to use alias name result in subquery in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find the below query.
For Eg:

```
Select (select count(loc_id) from TotalLocation_table) as TotalLocations,
 (select count(*) from EngagedccLocTable where loc in ( select loc_id from location_table) as EngageddLocations

//calculate the percentage of locations by using EngagedLocations and TotalLocations.used above queries to calculate percentage.

(select count(*) from EngagedccLocTable where loc in ( select loc_id from location_table)/(select count(loc_id) from TotalLocation_table)*100 as percentage

from loc_table;
```

Instead of using same query i want to use alias names to calculate percentage.

like `(EngageddLocations/TotalLocations)*100 as percentage`.

How to use this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below

```
Select (EngageddLocations / TotalLocations) * 100 as percentage
from
(
select count(tl.loc_id) as TotalLocations,
count(ec.loc) as EngageddLocations
from TotalLocation_table tl
JOIN EngagedccLocTable ec ON tl.loc_id = ec.loc
) X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with EngageddLocations as (select count(*) as  Engagedd 
                           from EngagedccLocTable 
                           where loc in ( select loc_id 
                                          from location_table))
,   TotalLocations as (select count(loc_id) as total 
                       from TotalLocation_table)
select EngageddLocations.Engagedd as EngageddLocations
,      TotalLocations.Total as TotalLocations
,      (EngageddLocations.Engagedd, TotalLocations.Total*100) as percentage
from EngageddLocations
,    TotalLocations;
```